# Open MarkLogic API Doc context-sensitive help in VSC

Tags: xquery, marklogic, vscode-extensions, api-doc

Is there an xquery-ml context-sensitive help feature with the MarkLogic visual studio code extension?

I am looking for a compatible feature like this one for sublime text https://packagecontrol.io/packages/MarkLogic#open-marklogic-api-docs

It will be useful for XQuery beginners.